# The type jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlets, jdbc

```
package sth.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import sth.hibernate.entitty.Users;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(Users.class)
                                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        
        try {
            
        } finally {
            factory.close();
            session.close();
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to getCurrentSession it's show me this error:

> "The type jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory cannot be resolved.
> It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: BTW: Add code as text not as image

Comment: BTW: Add code as text not as image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you miss the `jakarta.persistence-api` dependency in your class path.

If you are using maven, add the following to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```